# Has there been an increase in upvoting recently?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Is it just me, or has there been an increase in upvoting recently? Can mods determine any trends? Is there a reward for upvoting that could drive such an increase?

I'm thinking of question like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728071/whats-the-force-between-2-bodies-from-different-frames-of-reference), which to me make absolutely no sense as written, yet nevertheless received two upvotes.

Comment: A voting ring (voting fraud) *could* explain the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mod analytics tools show no remarkable trends - the total number of upvotes and downvotes over a time period correlates with the total number of posts made in that time period pretty well, and the ratio between up- and downvotes also hasn't really changed.

If you notice more (or more "unexplainable") upvotes, it's much more likely you happen to look at more or different posts than you did before, or you just started paying attention to different things.

Comment: Or I'm just getting crankier in my old age I guess...

Comment: I know I asked a bad/compound question, but I was also wondering about: "Is there a reward for upvoting...?" Either a literal/direct reward, or some indirect reward?

Comment: @hft The only thing you get from a certain number of upvotes are [some badges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges).